# how to copy package from VSTS to local server during build process

Tags: azure-artifacts

I created nuget task while configuring build definination, so that i can create a  package in VSTS(in package feed),  but my requirement is to copy that package to local machine while cretaing build.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent? If you're creating a NuGet package and putting it in a NuGet feed, why do you need to copy it to "a local machine"? Why can't whatever process needs the package invoke a NuGet restore?

Comment: Do you mean there is a build to create and push package and you want to download the package to a machine from another build?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a private agent (i.e. you're running builds on a machine or VM you've set up), you can use the [Copy Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/artifacts) task's "A file share" option in the "Artifact publish location" dropdown.